# How to publish database to provider in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio

My web application uses the MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database. To generate database script in Visual Studio 2010, I could right click on my database in Server Explorer, and choose publish to provider.

However, the menu for Visual Studio 2012 RC does not contain the publish to provider command. So how do I generate database scripts in Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be missing.. you just have to open up visual studio 2010 and publish to provider I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it :

http://arcanecode.com/2012/08/07/sql-server-data-tools-in-visual-studio-2012publish-database-profile/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103)

and you can also download tools :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027