# Visual Studio 2012 - Database Publishing Wizard Discontinued?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012 and SQL Server 2008 and have just noticed that the "Publish to Provider" option is missing in Server Explorer. According to this, Database Publishing Wizard has been discontinued?

http://forums.asp.net/post/5122271.aspx

How can I publish my database to my server now? Is generating scripts the only option instead of doing this from within the VS IDE and if so, can someone provide the steps to generate the DB with stored procedures included?

**UPDATE:**

- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538254/how-to-publish-database-to-provider-in-visual-studio-2012-rc) but unsatisfactory answer.
- [Confirmation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729467/database-publishing) that the wizard has indeed been discontinued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use SSMS in SQL Server 2008. Right-click database node in Object Explorer. Select Tasks -> Generate Scripts, and complete the wizard with the desired options. Not very satisfactory for a quick and simple deployment from within VS...

Some tutorials:

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/3/12/scripting-out-data-in-sql-server-2008-r2.html

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2500/sql-server-2008-r2-generate-scripts-wizard-with-database-schema-and-data/

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy/update database **schema** from Visual Studio:

1. VS2012: View -> SQL Server Object Explorer panel
2. right click on your database -> Schema Compare...
3. choose remote database as a target