# Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web Publish Database?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I need to deploy my database to a shared hosting enviroment and cannot use a file-based connection. The Database "Publish To Provider" option is not available anymore in VS2012 Express. I used to work with it in VS2010 and it was very handy. Is there any workaround to this in VS2012 Express? I know can use SQL Management Studio to generate the scripts but i'll have to attach the database for each project as i usually keep my databases in each project's App Data folder. There are also the SSDT but they don't work for VS express editions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: No answers yet but i found this similar post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782404/visual-studio-2012-database-publishing-wizard-discontinued

Unfortunately there is not a workaround at the moment for this.